# Angular: Adding EvenListener for a property in service from a controller

Tags: angularjs, service, controller, event-listener

Currently I have a Service:

```
angular.module('todoApp')
  .service('timeoutSrv', function() {
    var counter = 0;
function increment() {
  counter++;
}

function decrement() {
  counter--;
}

function getCounter() {
  return counter;
}

return {
  increment: increment,
  decrement: decrement,
  getCounter: getCounter
    };
  });
```

Then I want to attach an eventlistener, that "listens" for changes in the variable `counter`

My controller looks like this:

```
  angular.module('todoApp')
  .controller('TimeoutcheckCtrl', function ($scope, timeoutSrv) { 
    timeoutSrv.addEventListener(function listener(counter) {
        $scope.loading = counter;
     }) 
  });
```

I am getting the following error : `timeoutSrv.addEventListener is not a function`. How can I fix this ?

Comment: Can you please make a plunker for it?

Answer (score 0):

In Angular if you want to check for changes much like an eventListener in C# then you want to use the inbuilt function $watch:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

```
$scope.$watch("counter", function() {
  // Put code you want triggered in here
}
```

Comment: Could I somehow connect the $scope with the service? This is what i am currently struggling with.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, here's a Plnkr example of a simple incrementor utilizing the TimeoutService: http://plnkr.co/edit/FYUGBfIPtrl6Q7GWd597